# how to use wp_query three times in a page

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to show some posts on a page, so when i using wp_query() as the following the next and the last doesn't output any content, why?

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
<li>.....</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<li>.....</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '1' ) );
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<li>.....</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you went through the whole loop and there's no post left. You need to execute `wp_reset_postdata()`.

From the codex:

```
After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global 
to the current post in the main query.
```

Comment: i am sorry, i add <?php wp_reset_postdata();?> after each <?php endwhile; ?>, the two and three still have no output

Comment: Try moving your first query to the end and see if your output is still from the same loop or if you get anything from one of the others

Comment: You can also try executing `wp_reset_query();` after each loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset post data after each query (right after `endwhile`):

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: i am sorry, i add <?php wp_reset_postdata();?> after each <?php endwhile; ?>, the two and three still have no output